# Postgresql: dblink_exec parametrized in stored procedure error

Tags: database, postgresql, plpgsql

I have a "style problem". I'm writing a Postgresql function and I have this query in the code:

```
INSERT INTO JUNK VALUES (1, 2, 3)
```

I want to get this query

```
INSERT INTO JUNK VALUES ('1', '2', '3')
```

The number of columns is not fixed. It changes.

So I defined this plsql code in postgresql:

```
SqlQuery := 'INSERT INTO JUNK VALUES  (1,2,3)';
SqlQuery := REPLACE(SqlQuery,'(','(''');
SqlQuery := REPLACE(SqlQuery,')',''')');
SqlQuery := REPLACE(SqlQuery,',',''',''');

-- RESULT -> "INSERT INTO JUNK VALUES ('1','2','3')"
```

I also defined it in this way (in one row)

```
SqlQuery := 'INSERT INTO JUNK VALUES  (1,2,3)';
SqlQuery := REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(SqlQuery,'(','('''),')',''')'),',',''',''');

-- RESULT (same) -> "INSERT INTO JUNK VALUES ('1','2','3')"
```

Someone knows an "elegant instruction better than REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE.... and so on?

Thank you in advance for your help

I tried to use it working with regular expressions or implementing a function by myself but I would like to use a Postgresql function or a some kind of libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Even when the number of columns is not fixed in PostgreSQL, you can use the `quote_literal` function and the `format` function to elegantly accomplish the appropriate transformation for your `INSERT` query. How to do it is as follows:

```
-- Define an array of values
values_array := ARRAY[1, 2, 3];

-- Use the format function to construct the query with single quotes
SqlQuery := format('INSERT INTO JUNK VALUES %s', array_to_string(array(select quote_literal(val) from unnest(values_array) val), ','));

-- Now, SqlQuery contains the desired INSERT query
```

This code creates the `INSERT` query dynamically, enclosing each value in the array in single quotes, and gracefully managing different amounts of columns. Compared to employing numerous `REPLACE` functions, it's a simpler and more sophisticated strategy.